# AppDomain.Execute Assembly gets stuck

Tags: c#, wcf, appdomain

I'm having issues with just this command `ExecuteAssembly`
I had my app running with pipes streaming data and I switched to wcf with netnamed pipes.
This has nothing to do with the issue.

The server, once starting, performs some operations, one of them is executing the assembly that runs the client and connects to the server.

CODE:

```
String modulePath = (String)path;
AppDomainSetup objDomainSetup = new AppDomainSetup() { ApplicationBase = Path.GetDirectoryName(modulePath) };
string moduleConfigPath = String.Format("{0}.config", modulePath);
if (File.Exists(moduleConfigPath))
{
    // This is important... in case the loding module has a configuration file.
    objDomainSetup.ConfigurationFile = moduleConfigPath;
}

//We give the new app domain the same permission its parent has.
System.Security.Policy.Evidence baseEvidence = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence;
System.Security.Policy.Evidence objEvidence = new System.Security.Policy.Evidence(baseEvidence);
objModuleDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(ChannelName, objEvidence, objDomainSetup);
objModuleDomain.ExecuteAssembly(modulePath);
```

I checked the paths, everything and everything seems correct and the .exe pointed from the path is executed.
But ExecuteAssembly gets stuck there and the following statements are not executed.

Any guesses?
Thanks

Comment: Does your .exe (modulePath) complete and exit or does it keep running?  I believe ExecuteAssembly blocks until your module returns.

Comment: my .exe main() function creates an instance of the client, connects and sleeps (infinite) butExecute assembly is not blocking

Comment: Actually I had this code working this way with pipe streams and it was not blocking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly()` executes the assembly and finishes when the assemble `.exe` finishes. 
I had a Sleep(Infinite) that make the assembly not to finish.